# In my Apache Server I can't seem to be getting mod_rewrite to work for some reason

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2

Updated - With more clarity of the mod_rewrite failure that I'm having.In Apache I have the following setup in the config file:

```
  LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

  DocumentRoot "C:/mywebdev/apache/www"
  RewriteEngine On
  Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

  <Directory "C:/mywebdev/apache/www">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from All
  </Directory>
```

I have the following in my vhosts config

```
  <Directory "C:/mywebdev/apache/www/test">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from All
  </Directory>

 <Directory "C:/mywebdev/apache/www/test/.htaccess">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from All
  </Directory>

  NameVirtualHost *:80

  <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot C:/mywebdev/apache/www/test
  ServerName www.test.me
  ServerAlias test.me *.test.me
  LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/library/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  </VirtualHost>
```

In the .htaccess file I have this:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/library/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

I know it is overkill but it's just to show that no matter what I do it's not working. I checked to see if mod_rewrite.so was in the modules folder and it is there. The module is not working for this or any other mod_rewrite rule I've attempted to use. From what I've read this should be working. Thanks in advance for any assitance.

Comment: What is it that you are getting?

Comment: Check updated question for new specifics.

Comment: I don't find any difference...

Comment: @Praveen Kumar - Sorry, it me some time to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but, the content:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/library/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Should go into the `.htaccess` file in that folder. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I thought you were able to put it directly in the  <VirtualHost></VirtualHost>. I believe the .htaccess is for when you go live on a public server/shared server.

Comment: Dude, it is in the folder where you put the contents. That rules should go into `C:/mywebdev/apache/www/test/.htaccess`

Comment: I just changed this to: <Directory "C:/mywebdev/apache/www/test/min/.htaccess">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from All
  </Directory>

Comment: I'm still getting nothing. I am getting an error report now. Allow me a minute to update with new error report.

Comment: The question with more clarity minus the minify plug-in/setup has been updated.

Comment: Boss, you should not do that. It should be `<Directory "C:/mywebdev/apache/www/test">` as it is a directory and not a file.

Answer (score 1):

Insert your rewrite code between this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>CODE</IfModule>
```

Comment: I just did this. I placed it within the <VirtualHost></VirtualHost>, still nothing and no errors.